# Control UIImageview animation flow with touch events

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview, png

I am using a UIImageView to simulate 3D by animating .png images. Is it possible to use touch events to control the flow of the animation? For example if I'm simulating a box can I rotate it left or right with my finger? If not can u point me in another direction?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there are two ways to do this, the hard way which is to use core animation to build the cube and rotate it upon swipe or touch, and the second (the easiest) is to add the .png sequence of animations to an imageView which is fired by a UISwipeGestureRecogniser.

First of all create your gesture recognisers, Usually just put in ViewDidLoad

```
 //Implement Swipe Views
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];
swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[_imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

Then implement your swipeRight method, which you've declared in @selector(swipeRight), with the animation that you want to play upon swipe...

```
-(void)swipeRight
{
NSMutableArray *animationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int animationSizeTwo = 30;

    for (int i=0; i< animationSize; i++) {

        NSString *zeros = @"000";

        if ( i >= 1000 ) {

            zeros = @"";

        }
        else if ( i >= 100 ) {

            zeros = @"0";

        }
        else if ( i >= 10 ) {

            zeros = @"00";
        }
        NSString *animationNameTwo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(imageName)"];

        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%d.png", animationNameTwo, zeros, i];

        [animationArrayTwo addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];


    }

    _imageView.animationImages = animationArray;
    _imageView.animationDuration = 1;
    _imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    _imageView.image = [_imageView.animationImages lastObject];
    [_imageView startAnimating];

}
```

Now whenever you swipe right the animation fire. You can copy and paste the UIGestureRecogniser code and change all methods around so you can have it firing both ways.. When you come to implement your swipeLeft just change the animation sequence count to be this:

```
int animationSizeTwo = 0;

    for (int i=30; i> animationSize; i--) {
```

That will rotate your animation in reverse.

Hope this has been helpful and let me know how you get on! T